# Trying renaming all files in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying the script below to rename all files in a folder.It is working fine,But when i am trying to run it outside the folder.It shows error.

```
import os

path=os.getcwd()
path=os.path.join(path,'it')
filenames = os.listdir(path)
i=0
for filename in filenames:
    os.rename(filename, "%d.jpg"%i)
    i=i+1
```

'it' is the name of the folder in which files lie.
Error:FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '0.jpg' -> '0.jpg'
Print is showing names of files

Comment: because the `os.path.join()` does not return what you expect it to. try printing `path` to see. The reason for that is the `os.getcwd()`. When you are not sure why things are not going as expected, print your variables or debug to see what values they are taking and work your way from there.

Comment: The problem is rather in `os.listdir(path)`, which only returns the filenames instead of dir+filenames.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis thanks for the tip. Newbie to python

Answer (score 4):

When you do `os.listdir(path)` you get the filenames of files in the folder, but not the complete paths to those files. When you call `os.rename` you need the path to the file rather than just the filename.

You can join the filename to its parent folder's path using [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join).
E.g. `os.path.join(path, file)`.

Something like this might work:

```
for filename in filenames:
    old = os.path.join(path, filename)
    new = os.path.join(path, "%d.jpg"%i)
    os.rename(old, new)
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention complete or relative path to file.

In this case, it should be

```
path + '/' + filename
```

or more generally,

```
newpath = os.path.join(path, filename)
```